# Pythonic way to avoid a mountain of if...else statements?

Tags: python

This has come up several times recently and I'd like to deal with it better than I have been: I have a series of attributes that I'm cross referencing between an object and a dictionary.  If the value is different between them, I want to set the object.attribute to the dictionary['attribute'] value.  I also want to keep track of what's getting changed.

Now, my first thought is to just use an if else statement for every attribute, but after writing a few of these it's apparent that I'm re-writing the same code again and again.  There has to be a DRY way to do this, where I specify only the parts that are changing every time, and then loop through all the attributes.

In production code, there are 15 different attributes, but my example below will just use 2 for simplicity.  I have some idea about how to do this in a clever way, but I'm missing the final step of actually setting the object.attribute equal to the dictionary['attribute'] value.

```
# Simulated data setup - not under my control IRL
class someClass:
    def __init__(self, name, version):
        self.name = name
        self.version = version

objA = someClass('Test1','1.1')        
dictA = {'name':'Test1','revision':'1.2'}

# My code below        

# option 1 - a series of for loops
def updateAttributesSimple(obj, adict, msg):
    if obj.name == adict['name']:
        msg.append('Name is the same')
    else:
        msg.append('Name was updated from %s to %s' % (obj.name, adict['name']))
        obj.name = adict['name']

    if obj.version == adict['revision']:
        msg.append('Version is the same')
    else:
        msg.append('Version was updated from %s to %s' % (obj.version, adict['revision']))
        obj.version = adict['revision']        

# option 2 - trying to be clever about this
def updateAttributesClever(obj, adict, msg):
    attributeList = (('Name', obj.name, adict['name']),
                     ('Version', obj.version, adict['revision']))

    for valTuple in attributeList:
        if valTuple[1] == valTuple[2]:
            msg.append('%s is the same' % (valTuple[0]))
        else:
            msg.append('%s was updated from %s to %s' % (valTuple[0], valTuple[1], valTuple[2]))
            # code to set valTuple[1] = valTuple[2] goes here, but what is it?
            # valTuple[1] = valTuple[2] attempts to set the desired value to a string, rather than the attribute of obj itself            


msg = ['Updating Attributes simple way:']
updateAttributesSimple(objA, dictA, msg)
print '\n\t'.join(msg)

#reset data
objA = someClass('Test1','1.1')        
dictA = {'name':'Test1','revision':'1.2'}

msg = ['Updating Attributes clever way:']
updateAttributesClever(objB, dictB, msg)
print '\n\t'.join(msg)
```

The idea being that this way, whenever I need to add another attribute, I can just update the list of attributes being inspected and the rest of the code is already written.  What's the Pythonic way to accomplish this?

Comment: You could merge all of this into a function/functions. It'll make your code look neater and your life easier.

Comment: It's in functions on my side - I just was trying to simplify for the example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`setattr()` is what you're looking for:

```
attributeList = (('Name',    'name',    'name'),
                 ('Version', 'version', 'revision'))

for title, obj_attribute, dict_key in attributeList:
    obj_value = getattr(obj, obj_attribute)
    adict_value = adict[dict_key]

    if obj_value == adict_value:
        msg.append('%s is the same' % (obj_value))
    else:
        msg.append('%s was updated from %s to %s' % (title, obj_value, adict_value))

        setattr(obj, obj_attribute, adict_value)
```

Comment: Thanks!  setattr() is exactly what I was looking for.  I should also remember to be smarter about tuple unpacking when using for loops - thanks for that as well.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for your:

```
class X(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2

x = X()

d = dict()
d['a'] = 1
d['b'] = 3

def updateAttributes(obj,dic):
    def update(name):
        val = dic[name]
        if getattr(obj,name)==val:
            print name,"was equal"
        else:
            print "setting %s to %s" % (name,val)
            setattr(obj,name,val)

    for name in ['a','b']:
        update(name)

updateAttributes(x,d)
print x.a
print x.b
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to think about creating a function which can take an arbitrary object and convert the dictionary of name/value pairs into something more meaningful.  It's not strictly a "Python" strategy but something that is fairly easy to do in Python because of its support of closures and how it treats objects under the hood:

```
def checkUpdates( obj ):
    def updated( dictionaryPrevious, msg ):
        for name, value in dictionaryPrevious.items():
            if( obj.__dict__[name] == value ):
                msg.append('Name is the same')
            else:
                msg.append(name + 'has been changed!')
                obj.__dict__[name] = value
    return updated
```

I am making one assumption, the names in the dictionary always correspond to the object variables.  If they're not the same you'll need to make a mapping.

**edit**:

`()` => `[]` and `object` => `obj`.  thanks guys.  Sometimes you go from one language to a few others and it all gets muddled.

Comment: I think you mean `object.__dict__[name]` instead of `object.__dict__(name)`. You also shouldn't use `object` for a variable name since it's also the name of a builtin. ;)

Comment: Looks like a decorator.  So I call it with `checkUpdates(obj)` and it returns updated, which is a function that takes the dictionary and loops through all values.  So the code would be `func = checkUpdates(objA)` then `func(dictA)`? Let me try that...

Comment: @caribou: Although it's a function creating and returning another function, it's not a decorator. Your guess on how to use it is almost right, but you'll also need to pass `func` a `msg` argument.

Comment: Won't work because dict's keys are not the same as object's attribute names. Also IMHO creating and returning a function does not seem justified here since it's only purpose appears to be to create a closure.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of answers are close, but to handle that fact that the name of the key in the dict don't match the corresponding object's attribute name, you'll need some way to handle that. This can be easily done by adding yet another dictionary mapping the names of keys in the dict to the names of the object's attributes.

```
class someClass:
    def __init__(self, name, version):
        self.name = name
        self.version = version

objA = someClass('Test1','1.1')
dictA = {'name':'Test1','revision':'1.2'}
keymap = {'name':'name', 'revision':'version'}

def updateAttributesGeneric(obj, adict, key2attr, msg):
    for key, value in adict.iteritems():
        attrname = key2attr[key]
        if getattr(obj, attrname) == value:
            msg.append('%s is the same' % attrname)
        else:
            msg.append('%s has been changed' % attrname)
            setattr(obj, attrname, adict[key])

msg = ['Updating Attributes:']
updateAttributesGeneric(objA, dictA, keymap, msg)
print '\n\t'.join(msg)

# Updating Attributes:
#   name is the same
#   version has been changed
```