# trouble in a piece of code python getattr()

Tags: python, getattr

I was reading a book *Programming Python* (4th edition) and I am stuck at a problem with a piece of code including `getattr`. It is a loop for finding an icon file but I can't figure where it is searching (in what order). I have basic knowledge of using `getattr` like it searches the `__dict__` for names, but couldn't figure this one out.

```
mymod = __import__(__name__)           # import self for dir
path = __name__.split('.')             # poss a package path
for mod in path[1:]:                   # follow path to end
    mymod = getattr(mymod, mod)        # only have leftmost
mydir = os.path.dirname(mymod.__file__)
myicon = os.path.join(mydir, self.iconmine)
```

The comments are from the book. The last comment says "only have leftmost" so why run the loop if we want
the leftmost - can't we do `path[-1]` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you are working on a python project in the folder `/home/py_project/`

If you are coding a module (.py file) using the following path:
`/home/py_project/modules/my_file.py`
and the modules are defined in `/home/py_project/modules/__init__.py`

then,

```py
mymod = __import__(__name__) #  import self for dir
print(mymod)
```

yields: `<module 'modules' from '/home/py_project/modules/__init__.py'>`

```py
path = __name__.split('.')
print(path)
```

yields: `['modules', 'my_file']`

The `for mod in path[1:]` is slicing the previous list and getting all items from 1 to inf, in this case, only 'my_file' is considered.

```py
for mod in path[1:]: #  follow path to end
    mymod = getattr(mymod, mod) #  only have leftmost
    # same as mymod = modules.my_file


mydir = os.path.dirname(mymod.__file__)
print(mydir)
```

yields: `/home/py_project/modules`

```py
myicon = os.path.join(mydir, self.iconmine)
print(myicon)
```

yields: `/home/py_project/modules/path_to_self.iconmine  #  I don't know what self.iconmine is, you didn't mention it.`

Always print (or debug) the steps to the understand the code.

## getattr()

The `getattr()` method returns the value of the named attribute of an object. If not found, it returns the default value provided to the function. For example:

The syntax of getattr() method is:

`getattr(object, name[, default])`

The above syntax is equivalent to:

`object.name`

Example:

```py
class Person:
    name = "Louis"

person = Person()
print('Name:', person.name)
print('Name:', getattr(person, "name")) # using getattr() is the same as person.name
```

Comment: thanks for answering but what is the role of getattr() here

Comment: Take a look now.

Comment: You're welcome, `getattr()` is particularly useful to avoid `if else`. [Examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640598/pythonic-way-to-avoid-a-mountain-of-if-else-statements)

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the `for` loop is to transitively `getattr` from the package to the final module. You can't simply `getattr('foo.bar.baz.quux')`, you have to do

```
mymod = __import__('foo')
mymod = getattr(mymod, 'bar')
mymod = getattr(mymod, 'baz')
mymod = getattr(mymod, 'quux')
```

which of course is exactly what the loop does when you unroll it.